# Check for a condition in windows in a Pandas Dateframe and returning last True value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the title gore, but here's an example code showing my issue.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'var': [True, True, False, False, False, True], 
'letter': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'S', 'Y']}, 
index = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

So I want to iterate through the index and check every 2 values for  a True value. If there's a True value in the 'var' column, I would want to capture the final True value in the 'letter' column in the window, otherwise, I would return False. For example, this would return

`['C', False, 'Y']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(df['letter'].where(df['var'])   # get letters if True
 .groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2) # for every pair
 .last()                         # get last True value (or None)
 .fillna(False)                  # replace None with False
)
```

Output:

```
0        C
1    False
2        Y
Name: letter, dtype: object
```

If you want a list, further add `.tolist()`.

Output: `['C', False, 'Y']`